# How to create two image output boxes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

http://postimg.org/image/7jsmjfchh/

Hi Everyone, I am trying to create a rock paper scissors game with javascript and i need to make an HTML design like the one displayed in the picture. I would like help or advice on how to create the two boxes in the middle of the page that will be used to display images of rock paper or scissors. This is the HTML code that I have done.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <head>
    <h1>Project 1- Sample Solution</h1>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class= "choice">
    <input name="player" type="radio" id="rock"
        value = "0" /> ROCK <br />


    <input name="player" type="radio" id="paper"
        value = "1"  checked="checked" />
                                 PAPER <br />


    <input name="player"  type="radio" id="scissors"
        value = "2"  /> SCISSORS <br />
    <button id = "play">
            PLAY
    </button>
    </div>

   <H1>PLAYER</H1><input type="text" id="outputImage" size= "100px" />
   <H1>COMPUTER</H1><input type="text" id="outputImage" size= "100px" />


    <div class = "answers">
    <li>YOUR WINS:<input type="text" id= "output" size="5" /></li>
    <li>MY WINS:<input type="text" id = "output" size="5" /></li>
    <li>DRAWS:<input type="text" id = "output" size="5" /></li>
    <button id = "newgame">
            NEW GAME
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src = "project.js"> </script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: to view the linked image, you must have a tumblr account :(

Comment: okay sorry, I'll change that

Comment: @RyanGill I just updated the image

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
div.game {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
}
div.game > div {
    float: left;
}
div.choice {
    width: 25%;
}
div.players {
    width: 50%;    
}
div.answers {
    width: 25%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6mdL511/4/)

Comment: I had to modify the html. Please look at the fiddle. This was more of a way to do it, rather than a copy/paste solution.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the check box hooked up. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6mdL511/6/)

Comment: Thank you so much! But I think the images are meant to be in the java scrip section because an image of a rock paper or scissor is supposed to show up when you press one of the selectors.